# React/Webpack and Highcharts Sankey implementation

Tags: reactjs, charts, webpack

I am currently working with React/webpack and I used this example:

```
https://github.com/vasanthk/react-es6-webpack-boilerplate
```

My goal is to implement a Sankey Diagramm. I was told to avoid d3 because it is the Assembler of Visualization Libraries (Not my Statement)

Well I want to use Highcharts which doesnt provide Support for Sankey (Not yet anyway).

Another Problem is my lack of experience in JS Frameworks. Well I found this, which is a Sankey implementation with highcharts:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9txkfn1e/6/
```

But now I am not sure how to bind this properly in my Framework, do you guys have an idea for that?
What should be my next steps?

best regards

Comment: What is it that you want to know? Asking for what your next steps should be is very vague.

Comment: basicly I am not sure if the code of fiddle is complete or what I need (maybe i missunderstood something there) but if it is truly a highchart implementation for Sankey I would need a hint how to embed it into my Framework.